# get csv of users with user_meta

Tags: query, export, csv

i would like to export all users with user_metas.

Right now my sql looks like that

```
SELECT 
    u.ID, 
    u.user_email,
    u.display_name,
    um1.meta_value AS first_name,
    um2.meta_value AS last_name,
    um3.meta_value AS phone_number,
    um4.meta_value AS salutation,um5.meta_value AS title
FROM wp_users u 
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta  um1 ON u.ID = um1.user_id
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta  um2 ON u.ID = um2.user_id
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta  um3 ON u.ID = um3.user_id
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta  um4 ON u.ID = um4.user_id
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta  um5 ON u.ID = um5.user_id
WHERE um1.meta_key = 'first_name'
  AND um2.meta_key = 'last_name'
  AND um3.meta_key = 'phone_number'
  AND um4.meta_key = 'salutation'
  AND um5.meta_key = 'title'
```

The problem is I would like to get all user and not only those with the meta_keys specified above.

How would I do that?

Comment: Can you remove the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  u.ID,
  u.user_email,
  u.display_name,
  um1.meta_value AS first_name,
  um2.meta_value AS last_name,
  um3.meta_value AS phone_number,
  um4.meta_value AS salutation,
  um5.meta_value AS title
FROM wp_users u
  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta um1 ON u.ID = um1.user_id AND um1.meta_key = 'first_name'
  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta um2 ON u.ID = um2.user_id AND um2.meta_key = 'last_name'
  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta um3 ON u.ID = um3.user_id AND um3.meta_key = 'phone_number'
  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta um4 ON u.ID = um4.user_id AND um4.meta_key = 'salutation'
  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta um5 ON u.ID = um5.user_id AND um5.meta_key = 'title'
;
```

that's the right one. thanks jgraup for the hint